# Making a factorial program faster?

Tags: c++, optimization, factorial

I've been trying to submit this to a website with programming lessons, but the judge keeps telling me that this program takes too long to execute :/

Problem Statement:

> Write a program that reads a non-negative integer `n` from the standard input, will count the digit of tens and the digit of ones in the decimal notation of `n!`, and will write the result to the standard output. In the first line of input there is one integer `D (1≤D≤30)`, denoting the number of cases to be considered. For each case of entry. your program should print exactly two digits on a separate line (separated by a single space): the tens digit and the ones digit of `n!` in the decimal system.

Input/Output:

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| 2 |  |
| 1 | 0 1 |
| 4 | 2 4 |

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int d,n;

int main()
{
    cin>>d;
    for(int i=0; i<d; i++)
    {
        cin>>n;
        int silnia = 1;
        for(int j=n; j>1; j--)
        {
            silnia=silnia*j;
        }
        if(silnia == 1) cout<<0<<" "<<silnia<<"\n";
        else cout<<(silnia/10)%10<<" "<<silnia%10<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I want to comment, but just like I have to figure out the problem statement as you haven't provided one, you'll have to figure out what my comment is :D

Comment: Anyways, puns aside, please put your problem statement in the question. That way, it'll be easier to understand for all of us, and then we'll be able to help you better :)

Comment: @kesarlingHe-Him "factorial" sounds like a clear problem statement.

Comment: @bereal, how is factorial of `2`, `2 4`? :)

Comment: You're doing a LOT of duplicate work. `i` appears to only be used to determine how many test cases are executed. You can re-use the results from previous runs.

Comment: I think this is one of those problems where the first number inputted is the number of times the program will test your algorithm. `d` here is the number of tests.

Comment: @drescherjm, I guess so :) Isn't it plain annoying when the count of test_cases has to be entered manually? I mean, why can't these guys simply run the program test_case number of times? 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since only the last 2 digits of `n!` are needed, any `n >= 10`<sup>**</sup> will have a `n!` with `00` as the last 2 digits.

A short-cut is to test `n`:  This takes the problem from `O(n)` to `O(1)`.

```
  int factorial = 0;
  if (n < 10) {
    int factorial = 1;
    for(int j=n; j>1; j--)
    {
        factorial *= j;
    }
    factorial %= 100;
  }
```

Or use a look-up table for `n` in the [0...10) range to drop the `for` loop.

```
---
```

<sup>**</sup> 10_or_more! has a `2 * 5 * 10 * other factors` in it.  All these factorials then end with `00`.

Comment: Your statement that any number bigger than 10 has a factorial with 00 at the end was really helpful here.

Comment: Great answer. However, I'm not sure this is really `O(1)`. The runtime isn't constant - that would require arriving at a solution without a variable number of iterations. Even though the the maximum value of `n` that's of any interest is 9, I think this is still O(n).

Comment: @3Dave -- O(1) does not mean that the time needed never changes; it means that there is an upper bound on the time, regardless of how large the input is. For this example, the upper bound is the time needed to compute 9! -- there is no input value that takes longer than that time.

Comment: @PeteBecker I stand corrected! Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4):

You can get rid of *inner loop* since `n! == (n - 1)! * n`:

```
  cin >> d;

  int factorial = 1;

  cout << 0 << " " << 1 << "\n";

  for (int i = 1; i < d; ++i) {
    /* we operate with last two disgits: % 100 */
    factorial = (factorial * i) % 100;

    cout << factorial / 10 << " " << factorial % 10 << "\n";
  }
```

**Edit:** Another issue is with

```
  silnia=silnia*j;
```

line. Factorial *grows fast*:

```
  13! = 6227020800 > LONG_MAX (2147483647)
```

that's why we should use *modulo arithmetics*: we keep not factorial itself (which can be very large), but its two last digits (note `% 100`), which is garanteed to be in `00..99` range:

```
  factorial = (factorial * i) % 100;
```

Or even (if `i` can be large)

```
  factorial = (factorial * (i % 100)) % 100;
```

Comment: I hope nobody learning about factorials or programming feels bad about having attempted a solution that uses an inner loop.  It's intuitive and logical to do so--it just happens to be very inefficient.  Consider, for example, how many of you, when asked "what letter comes before Q" have to sing the ABC song in your head _from the beginning_.

Comment: um, OP tells that `D` is the number of testcases, so you may consider to edit your answer.

Comment: @justANewbie I think it's pretty clear that Dmitry is not trying to provide a solution to the programming challenge, rather is illustrating (albeit with code) the relationship between n! and (n-1)! that the op can then use to improve their approach.  It's the "Teach a person to fish, feed them for a lifetime", sort of thing.